R - mutate using case_when with str_detect and & operator
Respondents to a survey (rows) will give a colour as an answer in one of four columns. The other three columns have the value "none". I am trying to create a new column that picks up the colour that's in one of those columns
# example dataframe

am1 <- c('blue', 'blue', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'blue', 'none')
am2 <- c('none', 'none', 'red', 'none','none', 'red', 'none', 'none')
am3 <- c('none', 'none', 'none', 'purple', 'purple', 'none', 'none', 'none')
am4 <- c('none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'green')
mydata <- data.frame(am1, am2, am3, am4)


# my attempt to use case_when

mydata1 <- mydata %>%mutate(chosen_colour =
case_when(
str_detect(am1, "none") ~ am2,
str_detect(am1, "none") & str_detect(am2, "none") ~ am3,
str_detect(am1, "none") & str_detect(am2, "none") & str_detect(am3, "none") ~ am4,   
TRUE ~ am1

Does not work when using & operator - as chosen_colour should always have a colour as a value:



am1
am2
am3
am4
chosen_colour




blue
none
none
none
blue


blue
none
none
none
blue


none
red
none
none
red


none
none
purple
none
none


none
none
purple
none
none


none
red
none
none
none


blue
none
none
none
blue


none
none
none
green
none




You've gotten some alternative approaches but reading the case_when() docs will tell you why your approach doesn't work (the examples address this issue specifically), and that is that the statements are evaluated in order returning the first TRUE case so you need to arrange your statements from the most specific to the most general - i.e. reverse the order you've used (keep TRUE ~ am1 last, or better yet use the .default argument).

Thank you for referring me to the documentation, and that .default has replaced TRUE to be  "a more explicit and readable way to specify a default value."

If there is exactly one chosen colour you could use apply with setdiff:
apply(mydata, 1, \(x) setdiff(x, "none"))

With Reduce:
Reduce(\(x,y) ifelse(x == "none", y, x), mydata)

With dplyr and case_when:
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(
    chosen_colour = case_when(
      am1 != "none" ~ am1,
      am2 != "none" ~ am2,
      am3 != "none" ~ am3,
      TRUE          ~ am4
    )
  )


Note how  str_detect is unnecessary when you can use ==.

With base R subsetting
cbind(mydata, chosen_colour = t(mydata)[t(mydata != "none")])

output
   am1  am2    am3   am4 chosen_colour
1 blue none   none  none          blue
2 blue none   none  none          blue
3 none  red   none  none           red
4 none none purple  none        purple
5 none none purple  none        purple
6 none  red   none  none           red
7 blue none   none  none          blue
8 none none   none green         green

or, with reframe and tibble
library(dplyr)

tibble(mydata, chosen_colour = t(mydata)[mydata %>% 
  reframe(t(across(everything(), ~ .x != "none"))) %>% 
  unlist()])
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  am1   am2   am3    am4   chosen_colour
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>        
1 blue  none  none   none  blue         
2 blue  none  none   none  blue         
3 none  red   none   none  red          
4 none  none  purple none  purple       
5 none  none  purple none  purple       
6 none  red   none   none  red          
7 blue  none  none   none  blue         
8 none  none  none   green green


Here is an alternative approach:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = am1:am4, .fns = ~ if_else(. != "none", ., NA_character_), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite("chosen_color", starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ')

  am1  am2    am3   am4 chosen_color
1 blue none   none  none         blue
2 blue none   none  none         blue
3 none  red   none  none          red
4 none none purple  none       purple
5 none none purple  none       purple
6 none  red   none  none          red
7 blue none   none  none         blue
8 none none   none green        green


This is a good use case for dplyr::coalesce, inspired by the SQL function of the same name. However, it works with NA's instead of "none", so here I convert those to NAs, use coalesce, and then switch the NA's back to "none."
library(tidyverse)
mydata |>
  mutate(across(am1:am4, ~if_else(.x == "none", NA_character_, .x))) |>
  mutate(chosen_color = coalesce(am1,am2,am3,am4)) |>
  mutate(across(am1:am4, ~str_replace_na(.x, "none")))

   am1  am2    am3   am4 chosen_color
1 blue none   none  none         blue
2 blue none   none  none         blue
3 none  red   none  none          red
4 none none purple  none       purple
5 none none purple  none       purple
6 none  red   none  none          red
7 blue none   none  none         blue
8 none none   none green        green


Just for reference:
The tidyverse solution to row-wise aggregations is rowwise + c_across:

c_across() is designed to work with rowwise() to make it easy to perform row-wise aggregations.

One possible take like that:
mydata %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(choosen = detect(c_across(starts_with("am")), \(x) x != "none"))

purrr::detect will keep the first match left-to-right.
Output:
# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Rowwise: 
  am1   am2   am3    am4   choosen
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  
1 blue  none  none   none  blue   
2 blue  none  none   none  blue   
3 none  red   none   none  red    
4 none  none  purple none  purple 
5 none  none  purple none  purple 
6 none  red   none   none  red    
7 blue  none  none   none  blue   
8 none  none  none   green green

